# Transpose a File in unix

Tags: linux, unit-testing, unix, grep

I have file something like this

```
1111,K1
2222,L2
3333,LT50
4444,K2
1111,LT50
5555,IA
6666,NA
1111,NA
2222,LT10
```

Output that is need

```
1111,K1,LT50,NA
2222,L2,LT10
3333,LT50
4444,K2
5555,IA
6666,NA
```

1 st Column number may repeat anytime but output that i need is sort and uniq

Comment: how is this related to unit-testing ? A hash of key to list<values> can be populated in one pass and then iterate over the hash to get the output that you need.

Comment: You probably just want to write a simple script in a language with hashes and regex support, e.g. Perl.

Answer (score 5):

```
awk -F"," '{a[$1]=a[$1]FS$2}END{for(i in a) print i,a[i]}' file | sort
```

If you have a big file, you can try printing the items out every few lines eg 50000

```
BEGIN{FS=","}
{ a[$1]=a[$1]FS$2 }
NR%50000==0 {
  for(i in a) { print  a[i] }
  delete a  #delete array so it won't take up memory
}
END{
  for(i in a){ print a[i] }
}
```

Comment: ghostdog74 Thanks for your reply.. your script working fine. but i have one problem, I have file more than 20Lakhs Rows.. For loop that you have use may take much time. you have any suggestion for this.

Comment: what is 20Lakhs rows? awk is a pretty fast text processing tool. I highly doubt it will be slow for your problem.

Comment: like i said, what is 20Lakhs? what does Lakhs mean??? put those in numbers.... 20000 lines?? 2000000 lines??

Comment: so how long goes it take to run the script on your system? 10mins?? 30 mins??

Comment: well, another approach since you have big file, is to break your file up and perform the operation separately. Then at the end of it, combine the results.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an understandable try using a non-standard tool, SQLite shell. Database is in-memory.

```
echo    'create table tmp (a int, b text);
        .separator ,
        .import file.txt tmp
        .output out.txt
        SELECT a, group_concat(b) FROM tmp GROUP BY a ORDER BY a ASC;
        .output stdout
        .q' | sqlite
```

Answer (score 1):

This is solution in python. Script reads data from stdin.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
d = {}
for line in sys.stdin.readlines():
  pair = line.strip().split(',')
  d[pair[0]] = d.get(pair[0], [])
  d[pair[0]].append(str(pair[1]))
for key in sorted(d):
  print "%s,%s" % (key, ','.join(d[key]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one in Perl, but it isn't going to be particularly efficient:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
my %lines;
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    my ($key, $value) = split /,/;
    $lines{$key} .= "," if $lines{$key};
    $lines{$key} .= $value;
}

my $key;
for $key in (keys(%lines)) {
    print "$key,$lines{$key}\n";
}
```

Use like this:

```
$ ./command <file >newfile
```

You will likely have better luck with a multiple-pass solution, though. I don't really have time to write that for you. Here's an outline:

1. Grab and remove the first line from the file.
2. Parse through the rest of the file, concatenating any matching line and removing it.
3. At the end of the file, output your new long line.
4. If the file still has content, loop back to 1.